# How to make an inherited AUTOLOAD for non-method work?

Tags: windows, perl, console

```
package My::Win32::Console;
use warnings;
use strict;
use parent qw( Win32::Console );

sub new {
    my($class, $param1, $param2) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    if (defined($param1)
    and ($param1 == constant("STD_INPUT_HANDLE",  0)
    or   $param1 == constant("STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE", 0)
    or   $param1 == constant("STD_ERROR_HANDLE",  0)))
    {
        $self->{'handle'} = _GetStdHandle($param1);
        # https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=33513#txn-577224:
        $self->{'handle_is_std'} = 1;
    }
    else {
        $param1 = constant("GENERIC_READ", 0)    | constant("GENERIC_WRITE", 0) unless $param1;
        $param2 = constant("FILE_SHARE_READ", 0) | constant("FILE_SHARE_WRITE", 0) unless $param2;
        $self->{'handle'} = _CreateConsoleScreenBuffer($param1, $param2,
                                              constant("CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER", 0));
    }
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub DESTROY {
    my($self) = @_;
    # https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=33513#txn-577224:
    #_CloseHandle($self->{'handle'});
    _CloseHandle($self->{'handle'}) unless $self->{'handle_is_std'};
}

1;
__END__
```

When I try to apply this patch https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=33513#txn-577224 with the help of this module I get this error message:

```
# Use of inherited AUTOLOAD for non-method My::Win32::Console::constant()
# is no longer allowed at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/My/Win32/Console.pm line 10.
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: It says _"is no longer allowed"_ meaning it was deprecated. You can build a sub in that script to overcome it.

Comment: I could post an answer with a `sub` example but with untested code (on my phone and not close to laptop) which will get me downvotes. But also see [perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) . Search for **Use of inherited AUTOLOAD for non-method %s() is deprecated** you could find the autoload code in the modules and replace it.

Comment: Re "*How to make an inherited AUTOLOAD for non-method work?*", That question makes no sense. Inheritance is specific to methods.

Comment: How could I change the question so that it makes sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling a number of Win32::Console subs as if they were in My::Win32::Console.

---

Solution 1: Properly reference the subs.

- Replace the five instances of `constant` with `Win32::Console::constant`.
- Replace the single instance of `_CreateConsoleScreenBuffer` with `Win32::Console::_CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`.
- Replace the single instance of `_CloseHandle` with `Win32::Console::_CloseHandle`.

---

Solution 2: Import the needed subs.

Add the following:

```
BEGIN {
   *My::Win32::Console::constant                   = \&Win32::Console::constant;
   *My::Win32::Console::_CreateConsoleScreenBuffer = \&Win32::Console::_CreateConsoleScreenBuffer;
   *My::Win32::Console::_CloseHandle               = \&Win32::Console::_CloseHandle;
}
```

---

That said, I think inheritance is inappropriate here (and poorly done). Monkey-patching would be preferred.

```
package Win32::Console::PatchForRT33513;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::Console qw( );

{
    my $old_new = Win32::Console->can('new');
    my $new_new = sub {
        my ($class, $param1, $param2) = @_;
        my $self = $old_new->(@_);
        $self->{handle_is_std} = 1
            if defined($param1)
               && (  $param1 == Win32::Console::constant("STD_INPUT_HANDLE",  0)
                  || $param1 == Win32::Console::constant("STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE", 0)
                  || $param1 == Win32::Console::constant("STD_ERROR_HANDLE",  0)
                  );

        return $self;
    };

    no warnings qw( redefine );
    *Win32::Console::new = $new_new;
}

{
    my $old_DESTROY = Win32::Console->can('DESTROY');
    my $new_DESTROY = sub {
        my ($self) = @_;
        Win32::Console::_CloseHandle($self->{handle}) if !$self->{handle_is_std};
    };

    no warnings qw( redefine );
    *Win32::Console::DESTROY = $new_DESTROY;
}

1;
```

This way, modules that inherit from Win32::Console won't break, and you'll still be able to keep using

```
use Win32::Console qw( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
my $c = Win32::Console->new(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

as long as you do the following first:

```
use Win32::Console::PatchForRT33513;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I can explain it any better than [`perldiag`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perldiag.pod#Use-of-inherited-AUTOLOAD-for-non-method-%s::%s()-is-no-longer-allowed) (what you'd see if you `use diagnostics`)

> Use of inherited AUTOLOAD for non-method %s() is deprecated.
>
> This will be
>       fatal in Perl 5.28
>           (D deprecated) As an (ahem) accidental feature, "AUTOLOAD" subroutines
>           are looked up as methods (using the @ISA hierarchy) even when the
>           subroutines to be autoloaded were called as plain functions (e.g.
>           "Foo::bar()"), not as methods (e.g. "Foo->bar()" or "$obj->bar()").
>
> This bug will be rectified in future by using method lookup only for
>           methods' "AUTOLOAD"s. However, there is a significant base of existing
>           code that may be using the old behavior. So, as an interim step, Perl
>           currently issues an optional warning when non-methods use inherited
>           "AUTOLOAD"s.
>
> The simple rule is: Inheritance will not work when autoloading
>           non-methods. The simple fix for old code is: In any module that used
>           to depend on inheriting "AUTOLOAD" for non-methods from a base class
>           named "BaseClass", execute "*AUTOLOAD = \&BaseClass::AUTOLOAD" during
>           startup.
>
> In code that currently says "use AutoLoader; @ISA = qw(AutoLoader);"
>           you should remove AutoLoader from @ISA and change "use AutoLoader;" to
>           "use AutoLoader 'AUTOLOAD';".
>
> This feature was deprecated in Perl 5.004, and will be fatal in Perl
>           5.28.

The quickest fix, if you are expecting to be able to use `AUTOLOAD` in this class, is to say

```
*My::Win32::Console::AUTOLOAD = \&Win32::Console::AUTOLOAD
```

Comment: That doesn't actually help here since AUTOLOAD is simply masking the problem: The user is calling subs that don't exist (e.g. `constant`). Win32::Console's `AUTOLOAD` doesn't provide those subs, so your change simply changes the error to `Symbol Win32::Console::constant not defined, used at ...`

Comment: You should still leave the answer up for others that might fall across it, but maybe add something to it acknowledging that it doesn't help the OP?